# Cómo obtener solamente un elemento en la relación laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

tengo esta consulta

```
return LocationGroupPlace::with('place', 'place.site')->where('group_id', '=', $mainPlace[0]->group_id)->orderBy('type', 'asc')->get();
```

donde me está devolviendo site un array de n cantidad de items, quiero limitarlos a solamente el primero, intenté con esto

```
    return LocationGroupPlace::with('place', 'place.site')->whereHas('place.site', function ($subQuery) {
        $subQuery->first();
    })->where('group_id', '=', $mainPlace[0]->group_id)->orderBy('type', 'asc')->get();
```

pero obtengo un error de

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'places.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `sites` where `places`.`id` = `sites`.`place_id` limit 1)
```

y yo simplemente quiero que la consulta me devuelva el primer objeto de la relación y no todos

cómo puedo resolverlo?

Comment: Es una relación 1:N pero quieres obtener solo un registro en esta consulta en particular? Pregunto porque el nombre de la relación es `place` y no `places`, lo que dá a pensar que es sólo uno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta función:

```
return LocationGroupPlace::with('place', 'place.site')->where('group_id', '=', $mainPlace[0]->group_id)->orderBy('type', 'asc')->get();
```

prueba a cambiar el get() por first() para obtener sólo la primera ocurrencia de la secuencia.